# How do I reclaim virtual memory?

Tags: memory, vmware

I am a complete newbie at VMWare, so forgive me if this question is something that would be considered basic.

After you delete a virtual machine, how do you reclaim the virtual memory/ hard disk and turn it back into physical memory?

If that doesn't make sense, I probably am not saying it right, but basically, I lost a huge chunk of space and am looking to reclaim that space.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the virtual machine is powered off then it's not using virtual memory at all, more information is required to help

Comment: What do you mean by "space"? Disk space?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think it is obvious that he means disk space. He uses the word "Hard Disk".

Comment: @lzam But he also says he wants to "turn it back into physical memory".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think he just doesn't know the correct terminology very well.

Comment: @lzam I believe he is talking about both ram and his hard drive. " reclaim the virtual memory/ hard disk".

Answer (score 0):

Programs on your computer are able to use your ram, but once you stop them they free the ram backup. Virtual Machines get memory the same way, and once you close them the memory is re-freed.

You can verify this using the command `systeminfo |find "Available Physical Memory"`. Here's an example:

[image]

As you can see as the VM powers off it gives back the memory it was using.

As far as hard drive space goes, you can re-claim the space by deleting the virtual machine from your hard drive. Typically stored in a folder of the same name as the machine, with a large virtual hard drive file, and some small configuration files. Just navigate to where you saved the virtual machine, and delete it.

In VMware Player the default save location is "C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\Documents\Virtual Machines\THEVIRTUALMACHINENAME"